Добавить в манифест значение fps потока/ffmpeg
-filter:v:0 scale=-2:360,fps=30 
-adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a"

В js достаю информацию о потоках:
console.log(this.dsh.getBitrateInfoListFor('video'));


0 - строчка, это через js добавил объект(не берем во внимание)
Если верно понимаю, то через adaptation_sets возможно добавить еще параметры. Как добавить указанный fps потока? Чтобы в манифесте как то так было
<Representation id="2" mimeType="video/webm" codecs="vp09.00.30.08" bandwidth="512000" fps="30" width="854" height="480" sar="1280:1281">
    <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" initialization="init-$RepresentationID$.webm" media="chunk-$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.webm" startNumber="1">
        <SegmentTimeline>
            <S t="0" d="16000" r="2" />
        </SegmentTimeline>
    </SegmentTemplate>
</Representation>

Возможно ошибаюсь, должно сработать...
